# How to set background color of Phaser 3 Game during runtime?

Tags: runtime, background-color, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser 3 Framework , but have expertise in Angular/Ngrx.

Currently , I am creating a Custom Phaser 3 Game Editor using Angular/Ngrx. Need to modify background color of the Phaser 3 Game at run time.

In Phaser 2+ version , 
Below code set background color of the game ,

```
game.stage.backgroundColor = "#4488AA";
```

But how to set game background color in Phaser 3 irrespective of scene ?

Do we need to set via Camera like below?

```
this.cameras.main.setBackgroundColor(0xbababa)
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Yes, changing it via the camera is the only way in Phaser 3.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the same background color regardless of the active scene, Phaser 3 has a `backgroundColor` property in the `GameConfig` object. You can see the documentation [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.GameConfig) and a working version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/brsullivan/o140cu28/2/).

```
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 600,
    height: 700,
    backgroundColor: '#4488aa',
    scene: {...}
};
```

You also have the option of creating a transparent canvas for the game and using a div underneath it to change the background color. To do this, you'll use the `transparent` property of the `GameConfig` object. You'll also want to make sure you use the `parent` property as well with a corresponding `<div id="gameContainer"></div>` in the HTML to make it easier to grab and modify the color beneath the canvas.

```
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 600,
    height: 700,
    parent: 'gameContainer',
    transparent: true,
    scene: {...}
};
```

Then, in the create method, you'll grab that parent item and modify the color:

```
    create() {
        var div = document.getElementById('gameContainer');
        div.style.backgroundColor = "#4488AA";
    }
```

You can see a working version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/brsullivan/c8qd47o9/2/).